# how to stop postfix MAILER-DAEMON emails

Tags: email, ubuntu, cron, postfix-mta

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with Postfix

Late yesterday, I added a package (ispconfig3) that modified my postfix configuration and also added an entry to the root crontab that was invoking a script.

At around 11PM last night, I uninstalled that package and went to bed. The uninstall deleted the script and it's directory ok. But it did not clean up the crontab entry.

Since cron had trouble invoking the script, it sent root@xx.org an email. But ispconfig3 had modified my postfix configuration, therefore there is no  mail transport capability. So a MAILER-DAEMON email was placed in the mail queue.

Overnight, (I'm guessing here!) cron wakes up every minute and tries to do the same thing. So by 7:00AM there are now 1100+ emails in the mail queue. But since postfix is messed up, I can't see them.

At around 8:00ish I realize that something is wrong with my email set up. I check postfix configuration, backout the changes and now I can get emails ok. I can send them, receive them, etc.

Then the flurry of emails start. Every minute or so, I get around 30 MAILER-DAEMON emails indicating that cron couldn't invoke the script. I check

> sudo crontab -l

see the stale command for the non-existing script. I clear it out:

> sudo crontab -e

I expect the emails to stop.

They don't.

In fact, every minute they seem to be increasing in number. I then spend a few hours looking at a ton of configuration files to try to figure out what is going on. By 11:00ish or so, it's up to 50+ emails coming in every minute.

I finally realized that this stream of emails was occurring because of the failures that occurred the night before and that it was going to go on for 7 days. The "7d" comes from a postfix configuration setting. (BTW I changed that to be "2d" i.e. only a couple of hours).

In any case, I solved it. I'm adding this post so others can save themselves some time. See below.

Answer (score 1):

Finally hit on the idea to look at the mail queue.

A bit of googling and I found this site:
https://www.garron.me/en/linux/delete-purge-flush-mail-queue-postfix.html

I tried

> postqueue -p

which listed all of the "(mail transport unavailable)" emails:

> ... snip ...
>
> -- 1104 Kbytes in 1185 Requests.

I then did:

> postqueue -f   # this flushes the mail queue
>
> postqueue -p
>
> Mail queue is empty

And all of a sudden email flurry ended.

Note: the website above said to use:

> postfix -f

that did not work for me. A bit of googling found the postqueue command.

Another note: I was worried there were emails in that mail queue that were not "mail transport unavailable", so I double checked all 1185 emails to ensure it was ok to purge them.